# Creating leading label style for point features using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

How can I create leading label style in ArcGIS Desktop?

I mean something like following image.

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what version of ArcGIS is in use, what documentation you've reviewed, what you've tried, and where that didn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maplex label manager will allow you to place and offset these label. This will however be based upon the digitised direction of the line. Use the flip tool to correct this as needed. X,Y offsets can also be used per label.